# Использование git как репозитория проектов и фреймворков

Tags: git

Чем плоха такая структура?

Красный квадрат - класс(**шаблон**), внутри имеет(для примера): bootstrap, jquery, webpack, gulp
Звезды - это отдельные проекты(**сайты**).
Мы используем один шаблон для всех сайтов.

Допустим нам понадобился футер из синего сайта, мы его перетащили к желтому и предопределили, как нам нужно. Из желтого нам понадобился еще какой-то блок для зеленого, мы взяли его. Далее выходит обновление шаблона и мы подгружаем зависимости для всех наших проектов и спокойно используем новые технологии в старых проектах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где границы репозитория, сколько их? Вы четыре сайта запихали в один репозиторий? Линии от класса/шаблона к сайтам какую логическую связь отображают, что значат? Возможно, вы понимаете структуру, но описали очень непонятно чтобы со стороны понять.

Comment: Вообще, описанное больше походит на хранилище типовых сниппетов для сайта. Открыл репозиторий, скопировал в текущий проект, закрыл.

Comment: git submodules?

Comment: Да именно, 4 сайта в один репозиторий их может быть и больше. Линии от Шаблона значит, что мы используем его наработки, тобишь вначале мы скопировали шаблон 4 раза, спустя какое-то время мы подтянули из шаблона обновление ко всем веткам(сайтам)

Answer (score 1):

В таком способе использования я вижу 2 неприятных момента:

1. Сложная структура. У вас будет 5 веток, соответствующих привычному master'у. Нужно держать в голове, что, например, ветка task_123 должна быть вмержена в site1_master, а ветка task_234 - в framework_master. К тому же при перекрестных мержах история быстро становится нечитаемой.
2. Если у вас много часто изменяемых картинок (или любых других бинарников), то могут быть проблемы с производительностью.

Comment: 1. Можно ведь использовать более понятные название Допустим site1_task123 и сразу понятно к чему он относится

Comment: да, можно, но нужно держать в голове что так надо делать. Я не к тому, что так нельзя делать, а просто обозначаю подводные камни, а критичны они лично для Вас или нет - решайте сами.